# Extracting a list of values from an array faster

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a multidimensional array e.g.:

```
 T(1:3,1:3,1) = magic(3);
 T(1:3,1:3,2) = 10 * magic(3);
 T(1:3,1:3,3) = 100 * magic(3);
```

Now I want to extract certain values from `T`. The position of these values are given as a matrix:

```
 ind = [1,2,3;2,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3];
```

So the first value should be T(1,2,3), the second T(2,1,1) and so on.

Right now I am doing it in the following way:

```
for n=1:4
    output(n,1)=T(ind(n,1),ind(n,2),ind(n,3));
end
```

Where `output` should be

```
100
  3
 50
200
```

But this is really slow because I have much larger arrays in reality. Is there a way of accessing the values in a vectorized fashion?

So something like:

```
output(1:4,1)=T( ind(1:4,1:3) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert subscripts into [absolute (linear) indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) and then use these linear indices to grab specific values of `T`.

```
indices = sub2ind(size(T), ind(:,1), ind(:,2), ind(:,3));
output = T(indices)

    100
      3
     50
    200
```

If you need to do the opposite conversion, it's sister function [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) goes back the other way.