# Sample 1D vectors from 3D array using a vector of points

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a n channel image and I have a 100x2 matrix of points (in my case n is 20 but perhaps it is more clear to think of this as a 3 channel image). I need to sample the image at each point and get an nx100 array of these image points. 
I know how to do this with a for loop:

```
for j = 1:100
        samples(j,:) = image(points(j,1),points(j,2),:);
end
```

How would I vectorize this? I have tried

```
samples = image(points);
```

but this gives 200 samples of 20 channels. And if I try

```
samples = image(points,:);
```

this gives me 200 samples of 4800 channels. Even

```
samples = image(points(:,1),points(:,2));
```

gives me 100 x 100 samples of 20 (one for each possible combination of x in X and y in Y)

Comment: Regarding the duplicate vote: I don't see how [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991879/extracting-a-list-of-values-from-an-array-faster) addresses the tailing `:`.

Comment: @Daniel Yup I agree. I revoked the vote once I noticed that little detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise way to do this would be to reshape your image so that you force your image that was `[nRows, nCols, nChannels]` to be `[nRows*nCols, nChannels]`. Then you can convert your `points` array into a linear index (using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html?refresh=true)) which will correspond to the new "combined" row index. Then to grab all channels, you can simply use the colon operator (`:`) for the second dimension which now represents the channels.

```
% Determine the new row index that will correspond to each point after we reshape it
sz = size(image);
inds = sub2ind(sz([1, 2]), points(:,2), points(:,1));

% Do the reshaping (i.e. flatten the first two dimensions)
reshaped_image = reshape(image, [], size(image, 3));

% Grab the pixels (rows) that we care about for all channels
newimage = reshaped_image(inds, :);

size(newimage)

    100    20
```

Now you have the image sampled at the points you wanted for *all* channels.

Comment: The last sentence is not true, reshape is a "zero cost" operation, it does not create an additional copy of the data.

Comment: @Daniel Oh really? As long as it's not modified it's zero cost? Whelp learned something today!

Comment: Yes, the (linearised) data in memory is the same.

Comment: @Daniel Great! Thanks for the info. Maybe this approach was even better than I realized.

Comment: Maybe replace `size(image(:,:,1))`, indexing is not a zero cost operation. Here you copy a slice from the data just to get the size. Better use `s=size(image);inds = sub2ind(s([1,2]), points(:,2), points(:,1));`